# mongoDB aggregation with error msg

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to search for the word "credit" in my colloection suing the aggregation framework but I having an error. could anyone help figure out what the issue might be.

```
 db.complaints.createIndex({issue:1})

    db.complaints.aggregate([
{$match:{$text:{$search:"credit"}}},
{$project:{issue:1,_id:0}}
])
```

I am having this error:

```
    assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: error processing query: ns=customers.complaints l
imit=0 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=credit, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {
 $textScore: { $meta: \"textScore\" }, issue: 1, _id: 0 }\n planner returned err
or: need exactly one text index for $text query",
        "code" : 2,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: error processing query: ns=customers.complaints l
imit=0 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=credit, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {
 $textScore: { $meta: \"textScore\" }, issue: 1, _id: 0 }\n planner returned err
or: need exactly one text index for $text query",
        "code" : 2,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:15
2015-09-01T17:10:45.512+0100 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: error processing query: ns=customers.complaints l
imit=0 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=credit, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {
 $textScore: { $meta: \"textScore\" }, issue: 1, _id: 0 }\n planner returned err
or: need exactly one text index for $text query",
        "code" : 2,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:15 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

Comment: can you share your schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at your error message then you will see the following message: **need exactly one text index for $text query**.

Your post shows that you did create an index on `issue`. However, it appears that you do not have a [Text Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-text/) declared for your collection.

If you want the `issue` document field to be text searchable then create a **text index** as follows:

```
 db.complaints.createIndex({issue:"text"})
```

---

*(Note, you may only have one text **index** per collection. However, the fields included in the text index are established upon index creation. Again, see the abovementioned Text Index link.)*

Comment: You can only have one text index per collection, but you can create one text index for all string fields in the document using : 
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )

Answer (score 0):

This query will work:

```
db.things.aggregate([{$match:{issue:"credit"}},{$project:{issue:1,_id:0}}])
```

Comment: Thanks Clement, but I think @wyceewhite is right. missed to create a searchable index. thanks very much!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.